# Child travelling to Brazil with a valid Canadian passport but with an expired Brazilian passport

Tags: passports, paperwork, dual-nationality, brazil

My wife and daughter, who are both dual citizens (Canadian and Brazilian), are travelling to Brazil next week. We just realized that our daughter, who is 18 months old, has a passport that expired recently. There may not be enough time to get her passport renewed in time for departure.

Does anyone know if my daughter can still travel with my wife and be able to enter Brazil on an expired Brazilian passport?

Her Canadian passport is still valid and we will only be flying directly from Canada to Brazil.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Consulate General of Brazil in Houston](http://houston.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourist_visa.xml):

> ***Brazilian citizens even those with dual citizenship must enter and exit Brazil with a Brazilian passport.***

It doesn't look like there are any exceptions to this policy. However, an expired Brazilian passport may be sufficient. I would ask your local Brazilian consulate for a definite answer.

Comment: +1.  You should also contact the airline, since they will be the ones that determine if she can board.

Comment: Note this comment quoting a rule which specifically mentions expired passport + foreign identity document: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160904/can-we-round-trip-travel-to-brazil-from-the-usa-with-our-5-month-old-daughter-us?rq=1#comment401829_160915